# Wireguard client communication without peer key via 1 router server

Tags: routing, wireguard

I have this setup:

---server 1 config---

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.200.200.1/24
ListenPort = 6666
PrivateKey = server_private_key

[Peer]
PublicKey = client1_public_key
AllowedIPs = 10.200.200.2/32
PersistentKeepalive = 21

[Peer]
PublicKey = client2_public_key
AllowedIPs = 10.200.200.4/32
PersistentKeepalive = 21
```

--- client 1 config---

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.200.200.2/24
PrivateKey = client1_private_key
DNS = 10.200.200.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = server_public_key
Endpoint = server_ip:6666
AllowedIPs = 10.200.200.1/32
PersistentKeepalive = 21
```

--- client 2 config---

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.200.200.4/24
PrivateKey = client2_private_key
DNS = 10.200.200.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = server_public_key
Endpoint = server_ip:6666
AllowedIPs = 10.200.200.1/32
PersistentKeepalive = 21
```

---

I can ping server from client1 and client2, but i can't ping client1 from client2 and client2 from client1.

Is there a way for client1 ping client2 without adding client2 key to client1 config, since this will make addding client much harder. For example, if i add 1 new client when having 5 clients, all of the config must be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `AllowedIPs` setting of your client configs to `AllowedIPs = 10.200.200.0/24`, all the clients' traffic to the `10.200.200.0/24` block will be routed through their WireGuard connection to the server. This will allow you to connect from one client to another using their WireGuard addresses -- eg `ping 10.200.200.4` to ping client2 from client1.